# Why usual commands can't see a file within a cifs mounted directory?

Tags: rhel, find, mount, ls, cifs

I have a case where an existing file within a CIFS mount hosted DELL/EMC Unity appliance can't be seen by `ls`, `find` or `tree`. Only giving the absolute path of the unseen file makes ls and other commands to work properly. Strangely other files in that directory are seen. OS is RHEL 7.6.

From a native Windows client, all files including the "invisible" one Are listed without issue.

**Mount options in /etc/fstab**

```
//fileserver.domain.tld/my_mount$    /my_mount    cifs credentials=/secrets/.creds,dir_mode=0700,vers=2.0    0 0
```

**Directory real content**

```
/my_mount
├── file_01.ext
├── file_02.ext
└── file_03.ext
```

**Failing commands**

```
ls -l /my_mount 
tree /my_mount 
find /my_mount -type f -iname '*.ext'
```

*Result : Only "file_02.ext" and "file_03.ext" are detected, not "file_01.ext"*

**Successful commands**

```
ls -l /my_mount/file_01.ext
find /my_mount/file_01.ext -type f -iname '*.ext'
stat -c %y /my_mount/file_01.ext
```

*Result : "file_01.ext" is detected*

Note that the only difference between "file_01.ext" and the others is a huge ~50G filesize when others are in the range of a few Megas each.

Why usual commands can't see "file_01.ext" within this CIFS mount when only directory path is given to `ls`, `find` or `tree`?

Comment: @roaima: It is an SMB share provided by a DELL/EMC Unity appliance

Comment: @roaima: From a native Windows client, all files including the "invisible" one is listed without issue.

Comment: @roaima: Changing mount to vers=3.0 doesn't change the current issue unfortunately

Comment: Could it be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1572132 ? One other thing to try is to add `iocharset=utf8` and `noperm` to the mount options